# Nginx reverse proxy and expressJS get user real ip

Tags: express, nginx, proxy, ip, reverse

I'm trying to get the client real IP.

```
    location / {
  proxy_pass         http://docker-backend;
  proxy_redirect     off;
  proxy_set_header   Host $host;
  proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
}
```

When I check in all fields I can't find my real ip I allways get the reverse proxy IP.

Comment: What do you have set for your `trust proxy` in Express?

Comment: app.enable('trust proxy', true);